# JNLP File App Automation using marathon java driver

Tags: java, ui-automation, marathontesting

I am automating a forms application using java driver marathon. I can launch the application from the automation code and navigate to following the blocked screen.

There is a table where I want to read the data, I have the decompiled java code with me.
This method returns the focused row successfully.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("ListView229")).getAttribute("getFocusedRow");
```

`getFocusedRow` is a java method I can call it like above.

Now I want to call the =>

```
public final String getCellData(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)

driver.findElement(By.name("ListView229")).getAttribute("getCellData(1,0)";
```

I used the above code but returns null, I can call the java methods which does not have parameters.

How I can call the java methods which have parameters?

Comment: Can you attach the JNLP file used to launch the application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `driver.execute_script` to call the getters that require parameters. The following should work:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.name("ListView229"));
String s = driver.executeScript("return $1.getCellData(1, 0);", e);
```

Comment: Tried the same but getting the below error.  ('org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: net.sourceforge.marathon.javaagent.JavaAgentException:Script execution failed with an exception ([source error] no such class: oracle.forms.ui.ListView
Command duration or timeout: 104 milliseconds')